# Using fetch next with where in cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there any option to search inside cursor?
For example: I have a table(MyTable) with row number and value,
that I want to copy to another table(TestTable),
but let's say that if there was a value >= 5 then the next value,
that I want to copy should be <= 3.
I can use something like this:

```
create table TestTable
(row tinyint,
value tinyint)

declare @row tinyint, @value tinyint, @trigger bit
declare test_cursor cursor fast_forward for
select row,value from MyTable order by row
open test_cursor
fetch next from test_cursor into @row,@value
set @trigger = 0
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        if @trigger = 0
            begin
                insert into TestTable values (@row,@value)
                if @value >= 5 set @trigger = 1
            end
        else if @value <= 3 
            begin
                insert into TestTable values (@row,@value)
                set @trigger = 0
            end
        fetch next from test_cursor into @row,@value
    end
close test_cursor
deallocate test_cursor
```

That will work, but my question is: is there an any way to search inside cursor
for the next falue that <= 3 once trigger = 1,
instead of fetching next row over and over every time?

Comment: Often we can re-write a trigger in to a set-based method. If you tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve then perhaps a different [and better] approach can be provided.

Comment: Yes I know that set-based method would be preferable in most cases, but I don't think that it is possible to use set based method in this one, right now I'm using iteration solution to search for the next suitable value in my base table, and I'm wondering if there are some advanced options in cursor rather than going to next row every time.
Of course if you could think of set-based solution for that query it would be the best.

Comment: How do you define the "next suitable value"?

Comment: There is an example in my question once there was value >= 5 next suitable value is <= 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, cursors don't support the kind of querying that you're after. You will have to visit each value and check it in the loop.